# is there perfect way to check isset and is_numeric in 1 condition

Tags: php, isset, isnumeric

I want to combine these two conditions in one in PHP.

```
isset( $_GET['number'] ){
    is_numeric( $_GET['number'] ){
        /*----------------*/
    }
}
```

I tried below code but it is showing error

```
isset( is_numeric($_GET['number']) ){
        /*----------------*/
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just relying on the condition returning false if the value is not set or numeric, then you could use null coalescing to set it to some non numeric value and this will then fail the `is_numeric()`...

```
if(is_numeric( $_GET['number'] ?? "fail" )){
    // Is set and numeric
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help